# Highlighting a cell in excel then moving down

Tags: excel, vba

I know 0% VBA and I am in need of help. I need to create a VBA button that will highlight a row of cells and then move down 1 and then when the button is clicked it will repeat the above process.

Here is a snippet of what I am talking about:

[image: Excel snippet]

I would just want the above to be move down to the next row and then highlight those 3 columns and repeat.

Please let me know if you have any idea how I could implement this for "x" number of rows of data.

Thank you!

EDIT: Code below that I have tried

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sub Macro1()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A12:C12").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A13:C13").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try using the Macro Recorder of Excel? What was your result? Where did you get stuck or errors? Your question sounds like "*I know 0 % about rocket science but I want to fly to Mars*" … I have to say then you just can't. So you should at least show that you did some research and tried something to achieve your goal, instead of let others do your work.

Comment: Thank you Peh, I have tried recording a Macro however when I do it only highlights the cells that I have selected for that Macro. It doesn't take into account other cells below that given range. I hope I explained that ok?

Comment: *I need to create a VBA button* - reading [ask] will help you understand how to get best help here. Telling us requirements and asking us to write code is not one of them :)

Comment: (1) If you tried something then always show the code in your question ([edit]), so we can built upon this. (2) Explain what your code does and what you expect instead. (3) It is not clear what you try to highlight exactly by each button press.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? like @Peh says if you show us what you have we can improve it so that it works for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are all correct. I have listed the code from my macro above in the edit. I am sorry for being frustrating to help lol

Comment: So it is still not clear what you try to highlight **on each button click**: (a) One row at each click? (b) 3 rows at each click? (c) anything else?

Comment: I want to click the button and it highlights one row of data in yellow, then on the next button click it will move to the next line and highlight that row of data yellow, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following and it worked as you wanted:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Check the last row with data
For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop until you find the last highlighted cell
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 65535 Then
    x = i + 1 ' add one for the next row
    End If
Next i

If x > 1 Then
    Sheet1.Range("A" & x & ":C" & x).Interior.Color = 65535 'add colour to the next cell found in previous loop
Else
    x = 1
    Sheet1.Range("A" & x & ":C" & x).Interior.Color = 65535 'if no cell found in previous loop, highlight the first row
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would highlight the selected row and move one row down. Then waiting for the next button press.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub HighlightSelectedRowAndMoveDown()
    With Selection.EntireRow      'use the entire row of the selected cell
        .Interior.Color = 65535   'color its background yellow
        .Offset(1, 0).Select      'move selection one row down
    End With
End Sub
```